# Representation Theory versus Galois Theory.

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, galois-theory

At my university there is a debate about whether it is better to require students to have taken a class in Galois theory or to require a class in representation theory for admission into the graduate program. Currently, Galois theory is required for admission and rep theory is not. Many of the professors have argued that representation theory has a broader application and hence should be preferred over Galois theory on admissions applications. There are of course important links between the two topics, so I wanted to see what people at other universities have found to be more helpful in graduate school.

At my university, we teach Galois theory out of Dummit and Foote or a book by Ian Stewart. We teach rep theory out of a book by Martin Liebeck and Gordon James (If you are familiar with those texts).

Comment: Why not require students to have taken a class in Galois theory or a class in representation theory?

Comment: The closest thing I can see to a question here is *so I wanted to see what people at other universities have found to be more helpful in graduate school.* Is this correct? Questions like "what do you think is more useful" are a little too subjective. You might toss  it into the main chatroom though.

Comment: Yes, To clarify: I want to pick up some comments on what people have found to be more helpful in their graduate level research/classwork, Galois or Rep theory.